# Issue with textarea in Internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Below code only displays/accepts 4 characters as input in each row, where as I mentioned as 5.

I have upgraded my PC win7 recently. I am sure the textarea is working as expected in my XP machine.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<td><textarea id="txtNarrative" cols="5" rows="4">1234512345123</textarea></td>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how can I make it to accept 5 characters in each row.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? I see it as 5 characters wide in IE9. http://jsfiddle.net/SFSCP/1/

Comment: funny, in my Firefox (v17 Mac) its 6 characters wide!

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML Doctype in the first line of your document, that solved it for me on IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
...
```